# Can't save NSDictionary to FirebaseDatabase

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase

I am trying to save the following dictionary to my Firebase Database from an iOS/Objective-C application:

```
NSMutableDictionary* enrollmentDicc = {
"cleaning_tasks" = 3;
"eat_drink_dairy" = 2;
"eat_gluten" = 1;
"eat_meat" = 1;
"flor_lay_on_mat" = 2;
"garden" = 1;
"hours_spend_standing" = 1;
"level_of_flexibilitity" = 2;
"lift_or_carry" = "3,4,5";
"sit_bed_propped" = 3;
"strech_excercise" = "4,5,6";
"tight_calves" = 2;
"type_shoes" = "4,5,6";
"cause_back_pain" = "3,4";
"chill_sitting_room" = 1;
"cross_legs_sit_down" = 2;
diagnosis = "3,4";
"drive_everyday_hours" = 1;
email = "ignacio.orona+tw@gmail.com";
"has_diagnosis" = 1;
"hours_sitting_down" = 2;
"how_did_you_hear" = 3;
name = ignacio;
painLevelthisMoment = 10;
"pain_location" = 2;
processed = 0;
"sit_soft_couch" = 2;
"sleep_position" = 1;
treatments = "4,10";
```

For that purpose I use the following code:

```
-(void) apiPostEnrollment:(NSDictionary*)enrollmentDicc withCompletion:(SingleResponseCompletionBlock)completionBlock
{
    _dbNodeRef = [[[FIRDatabase database] referenceWithPath:@"enrolledUsers"] childByAutoId];

    [_dbNodeRef setValue:enrollmentDicc withCompletionBlock:^(NSError * _Nullable error, FIRDatabaseReference * _Nonnull ref){
        completionBlock(ref,error);
    }];
}
```

My problem is that the Dictionary does not get saved in Firebase, and I don't even have the response from the callback function (which ideally would give me some clue of why my data is not being stored. I've also turned on the [Firebase debug mode](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) with no luck either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem actually was that there was a hidden character (\x) in some of the keys of the dictionary. Erased those wrong hidden characters that came from only god knows where, and it worked like charm.